# Grafana alert if last point is more than previous points

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, grafana-alerts

We are using Grafana and Prometheus for monitoring system metrics. We have been following static rules so far but now want to have some dynamic rules as well.
Our requirement is to raise an alert if the current point is > 110% of max of last 24 points(2 hours).
Can I express this kind of query in grafana+prometheus? Can you please help me with the query.

I googled around it but couldn't find anything related to my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [multi-dimensional rules](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/alerting-rules/create-grafana-managed-rule/#single-and-multi-dimensional-rule). These rules will let you use Math and Reduction operations on the queries instead of the Classic Conditions.

For your specific need, make two queries, one returning the current value and one returning the max value. Reduce both of them (unless you already have [numeric data](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/evaluate-grafana-alerts/#alerting-on-numeric-data-1)) and use a Math operation expression that should look like `$A > $B*1.1`.